# While launching jar jdesktoppane background image not showing

Tags: java, swing, embedded-resource, jdesktoppane

My application moved from jdk6 to jdk8, netbeans 6 to NB 8.
In netbeans I am able to see application background image but when i create jar and launch app  with jar i.e
java -jar appName.jar

Everything working fine, just background image is NOT showing, instead I am getting blank background what I set in form(0,0,0) i.e black.

Please suggest is any property is set or overwrite. 
New to java UI

Comment: is your image packaged within the jar ?

Comment: yes, it is under src\resources\icon folder, where all other images are stored and shown.

Comment: Post a [mcve]..

Comment: Did you ever create a Jar using JDK 6 NB 6? Note: 1) Narrow the factors down. 2) Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.